# can't change action menu icon in android app

Tags: android, eclipse, application-design

It's less than I can't change it, (Since I already did), and more and issue that I can't change it BACK.

So I'm using eclipse to learn android app development. In one of the tuts on the android developer website, it says you have to add your own ic_action_search.png file for the action bar to find. (Else it won't compile). So I made my own goofy looking icon. I added it, and it's there. Ok.

So Afterwards, I found the Android Design Icon pack from google. It looks much better and decided to plug that back in. I thought that would be easy. I took the new file, (With the EXACT same names), and plugged them back into the source folder where the others were. It OVERWROTE the other files and I have confirmed that the correct icons are now in there.

When I run the program using USB debugging on my phone though, the OLD icon is still there.
I tried refreshing the folders inside eclipse. I tried uninstalling the app from my phone and then re-installing fresh using USB debugging in eclipse. Still no go.

I'm worried that my device stored those images somewhere in my phone and isn't overriding them on the new install. Really need help with this here.
Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try cleaning your project by: Project -> Clean?

Comment: which menu icon? homescreen launcher icons won't change. also, did you check all res folders for the old icon?

Comment: yes I did. I've confirmed that the NEW icons ARE in the res folder.

Comment: Cleaning the Project did the trick. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refresh your project <kbd>F5</kbd>
Go to
**`Project > Clean`**

if that doesn't work delete `/gen` and `/bin` folders of your project to recreate all the references of your resources.

probably you are uploading an .apk file with the old resources

Comment: I had refreshed the folders in the navigator but I never cleaned. That did the trick. Thanks so much!